# how to upload image (Multipart) using Alamofire 5.0.0-beta.3 (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift5

I am working on uploading image using multipart. This Code Working fine in **swift 4** and **Alamofire 4.** Please give any solution for this.

```
public class func callsendImageAPI(param:[String: Any],arrImage:[UIImage],imageKey:String,URlName:String,controller:UIViewController, withblock:@escaping (_ response: AnyObject?)->Void){

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ MultipartFormData in

        for (key, value) in param {
            MultipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }

        for img in arrImage {

            guard let imgData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return }
            MultipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: imageKey, fileName: FuncationManager.getCurrentTimeStamp() + ".jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

    },usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
      to: "URL",
        method:.post,
        headers:["Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                 "Content-Disposition" : "form-data"],
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, , ):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    switch(response.result) {
                    case .success(_):
                        let dic = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                        if (dic.object(forKey:  "status")! as! Int == 1){
                            withblock(dic.object(forKey: "data") as AnyObject)
                        }else if (dic.object(forKey: Message.Status)! as! Int == 2){
                            print("error message")

                        }else{
                            print("error message")
                        }
                    case .failure(_):
                        print("error message")
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("error message")
            }
    })}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please refer Below code.

```
public class func callsendImageAPI(param:[String: Any],arrImage:[UIImage],imageKey:String,URlName:String,controller:UIViewController, withblock:@escaping (_ response: AnyObject?)->Void){

    let headers: HTTPHeaders
    headers = ["Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
               "Content-Disposition" : "form-data"]
    
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        
        for (key, value) in param {
            multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        
        for img in arrImage {
            guard let imgData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return }
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: imageKey, fileName: FuncationManager.getCurrentTimeStamp() + ".jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
        
        
    },usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
      to: URL.init(string: URlName)!,
      method: .post,
      headers: headers).response{ response in
        
        if((response.error != nil)){
            do{
                if let jsonData = response.data{
                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                    print(parsedData)
                    
                    let status = parsedData[Message.Status] as? NSInteger ?? 0
                    
                    if (status == 1){
                        if let jsonArray = parsedData["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                            withblock(jsonArray as AnyObject)
                        }
                        
                    }else if (status == 2){
                        print("error message")
                    }else{
                        print("error message")
                    }
                }
            }catch{
                print("error message")
            }
        }else{
             print(response.error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Happy to help you :)

Comment: Hello, how to get the progress of uploading?

Comment: I spent more mins to find why i can't get response even error also nil, finally i found. Here it is, Need to change as "if((response.error == nil))" instead "if((response.error != nil))", But you saved my time thank you @dixit

Answer (score 12):

Almofire 5.0 & Swift 5.0

```
    //Set Your URL
    let api_url = "YOUR URL"
    guard let url = URL(string: api_url) else {
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0 * 1000)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //Set Your Parameter
    let parameterDict = NSMutableDictionary()
    parameterDict.setValue(self.name, forKey: "name")

    //Set Image Data
    let imgData = self.img_photo.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!

   // Now Execute 
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
        for (key, value) in parameterDict {
            if let temp = value as? String {
                multiPart.append(temp.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key as! String)
            }
            if let temp = value as? Int {
                multiPart.append("\(temp)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key as! String)
            }
            if let temp = value as? NSArray {
                temp.forEach({ element in
                    let keyObj = key as! String + "[]"
                    if let string = element as? String {
                        multiPart.append(string.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                    } else
                        if let num = element as? Int {
                            let value = "\(num)"
                            multiPart.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: keyObj)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        multiPart.append(imgData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }, with: urlRequest)
        .uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
            //Current upload progress of file
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { data in

                   switch data.result {

                   case .success(_):
                    do {
                    
                    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data.data!, options: .fragmentsAllowed) as! NSDictionary
                      
                        print("Success!")
                        print(dictionary)
                   }
                   catch {
                      // catch error.
                    print("catch error")

                          }
                    break
                        
                   case .failure(_):
                    print("failure")

                    break
                    
                }


        })
```

Happy to help you :)

Its Work for me