# Send image from iOS Alamofire to Vapor

Tags: ios, swift, vapor

I have an application where user can update their profile picture.
The application is developed in SwiftUI and used Alamofire to perform API request and the server is developed with Vapor.
When I tried to send the picture to the server, I got this error:

> [ WARNING ] Value required for key 'filename'. [request-id: A5083FA1-657C-4777-A7FF-9D02E2A66703]

Here is the code from Vapor:

```
private func updatePicture(req: Request) async throws -> Response {
        let file = try req.content.decode(File.self)
        guard let fileExtension = file.extension else { throw Abort(.badRequest)}
        
        return .init(status: .accepted, headers: getDefaultHttpHeader(), body: .empty)
    }
```

And here is the iOS code:

```
func uploadFiles(urlParams: [String], method: HTTPMethod, user: User, image: UIImage, completionHandler: @escaping ((Data?, HTTPURLResponse?, Error?)) -> Void) {
        guard let formattedUrl = URL(string: "\(url)/\(urlParams.joined(separator: "/"))") else {
            completionHandler((nil, nil, nil))
            return
        }
        var headers: HTTPHeaders?
        headers = ["Authorization" : "Bearer \(user.token)"]
        
        let multiPart: MultipartFormData = MultipartFormData()
        multiPart.append(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9), withName: "data", fileName: "filename", mimeType: "image/jpeg" )

        AF.upload(multipartFormData: multiPart, to: formattedUrl, method: .patch, headers: headers).response { data in
            print(data)
        }.resume()
    }
```

I followed vapor and Alamofire documentation and I still get this issue.

Is anyone can help me with this issues ?

Comment: What does your File struct look like?

Comment: Need to set "Content-type": "multipart/form-data" for header. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264097/upload-files-with-parameters-from-multipartformdata-using-alamofire-5-in-ios-swi

Answer (score 1):

On the Vapor side you have to use struct with File field inside

```swift
struct PayloadModel: Content {
    let data: File
}

private func updatePicture(req: Request) async throws -> HTTPStatus {
    let payload = try req.content.decode(PayloadModel.self)
    guard let fileExtension = payload.data.extension else {
        throw Abort(.badRequest)
    }

    return .accepted
}
```